# How can you recursively copy all of the *.foo files in src to target using cp and/or find?

Tags: copy, cygwin, find, cp

```
cp -v -ur path/to/jsps/ /dest/path/
```

The above command copies all of the files that have been updated from the source directory to the destination, preserving the directory structure.

What I can't figure out is how to copy only *.someExtention files. I know that you can use something like:

```
find -f -name *.jsp -exec some awesome commands {}
```

But I don't know how to do it (and I don't have time to read the info pages in detail).

All help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
LES

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use find / cp then the following should do the trick:

```
find -f -name *.jsp -exec cp --parents {} /dest/path \;
```

but rsync is probably the better tool.

Comment: I have not tested yet, but it looks like what I need. Thanks!

I do some web dev and I often need to change a jsp and then copy the file over to the target directory (mvn directory structure). Rsync might be overkill.

Answer (score 4):

[rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/) might help - you can tell it to just copy certain files with a combination of include and exclude options, e.g.

```
rsync -a \
   --include='*.foo' \
   --include='*/' \
   --exclude='*' \
   path/to/jsps/ /dest/path/
```

See the [manual](http://samba.anu.edu.au/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) and look at the section entitled FILTER RULES for more.

Comment: +1. You could make this work with find and cp, but rsync is really the better tool to use.